# AND operator on file permissions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-permissions

I am trying to write a function that takes in two strings and returns the AND operation of them.

For example, with file permissions 755 & 664 should return 644.

```
def compareBits(desired, existing)
    return desired.to_i(2) & existing.to_i(2)

end

compareBits('0755', '0664')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: File permissions are usually stored as numbers in Ruby, i.e. `0664` instead of `'0644'`. It might make sense to do the same in your program and just convert it for displaying purposes.

Comment: So, what did you actually get?

Answer (score 5):

Your mode strings (`'0755'` and `'0664'`) are in octal but calling `to_i(2)` treats them as binary, you want to call [`#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) with a `base` argument of eight. You're also calling `to_i` on `desired` twice instead of calling it on both arguments:

```
def compareBits(desired, existing)
  desired.to_i(8) & existing.to_i(8)
end
```

That will give you a numeric result. If you want an octal string back then add a `to_s(8)` call:

```
def compareBits(desired, existing)
  (desired.to_i(8) & existing.to_i(8)).to_s(8)
end
```

Comment: `desired.to_i(8)` → `desired.oct`